# python Django named vs positional arguments for url routing

Tags: python, django, url

I have the following in my app for url routing:

urls.py

```
urlpatterns = patterns('rocflavors.views',
   url('^detail/(?P<content_type>[^/]+)/(?P<slug>[^/]+)/(?P<asset_id>\d{1,32})$', 'flavors_detail', name='flavors_detail'),
)
```

views.py

```
def flavors_detail(request, slug, asset_id, content_type, format="html"):
```

It seems that the arguments I am using are named arguments. (content_type, slug, asset_id).

How does Django/python know when to pass positional arguments vs keyword arguments?

The `flavors_detail` function accepts 5 arguments, but in the url they are out of order.

Answer (score 2):

To answer your question, `flavor_detail` will accept four arguments (in order) and one keyword argument. The regexp in `url` will pass the matches it finds in order, but as you've also defined a keyword for each arg it will instead pass a `kwarg` dictionary. As you've kept the variable names consistent this `dict` will pass the correct args in the correct place (if you had used different variable names this would not have worked). You can avoid this 'magic' by simply specifying keyword arguments for `flavors_detail` as described below.

Your `url` is a regular expression which defines them:

```
 ?P<content_type>
```

will produce the `kwarg` `content_type`. Check out the `re` module in python ([docs](http://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html)).

> `(?P<name>...)`
>   Similar to regular parentheses, but the substring matched by the group is accessible within the rest of the regular expression via the symbolic group name name. Group names must be valid Python identifiers, and each group name must be defined only once within a regular expression. A symbolic group is also a numbered group, just as if the group were not named. So the group named id in the example below can also be referenced as the numbered group 1.

As you are defining your variables as keyword args `kwargs` you could to change your view declaration to accept kwargs:

```
def flavors_detail(request, slug=slug, asset_id=asset_id, content_type=content_type, format="html"):
```

However, Python will also accept your previous definition (my comment was premature), so long as you're careful to preserve the argument order! There is more information on how this happend [here](http://docs.python.org/2/reference/expressions.html#calls) - to quote

> If keyword arguments are present, they are first converted to positional arguments

Comment: So based on what I call the variable in my function it will map to that and order does not matter?

Comment: Yeah, so `content_type` will always be what occurs after `detail` in your url, and as it's a `kwarg` the order in `flavors_detail` doesn't matter (but you will still need `def flavors_detail(request, slug=slug, asset_id=asset_id, content_type=content_type, format="html"):`

Comment: I didn't have slug=slug, asset_id=asset_id and it still worked. How is this possible? What I had above is exactly how it was defined.